# Invoking method of a class as another class' attribute in Matlab

Tags: matlab, class

*Apologize if the title is confusing.*

I tried to set an attribute of a class as another class:

```
classdef gun
    properties
        bullets;
        ...
```

Where `bullets` is later initialized as another class object `bullets = bul(10);`

```
classdef bul
    properties
        ...
    methods
        function obj = addBullet(obj, num)
            ...
```

But when I tried to invoke method `addBullet` in class `gun`, like `gun.bullets.addBullet(2)`, I got an error saying:

```
Dot indexing is not supported for variables of this type.
```

Is it because Matlab does not support class as another class' attribute? Any way I can fix that?

Comment: It is likely because `bullets` hasn’t been initiated yet. There is nothing wrong about what you are trying to do. Use the debugger! `dbstop if error` will let you examine the contents of variables when an error occurred.

Comment: Also, if you can’t find the issue using the debugger, post a [mcve], the question now does not have enough information to point out the reason for your error message.

Comment: @CrisLuengo yes, you're right. I rewrite a simplified version and it worked. I think it was caused by some false initialization.